# Why calling member function declared and defined in another file gives link error?

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, lnk2019

I'm trying to call a public member function:

```
// main.cpp
#include "AH.h"
int somefunc()
{
//...
// it - object of class A
    it.set_mean(angle, mean);
//...
}
```

that declared in .h

```
// AH.h
class A
{
//...
public:
   inline void set_mean(const int angle, const double mean_value);
//...
}
```

and defined in .cpp file:

```
// A.cpp
#include "AH.h"
inline void A::set_mean(const int angle, const double mean_value)
{
    mean[angle] = mean_value;
}
```

and recieving an LNK error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl A::set_mean(int,double)" (?set_mean@A@@QEAAXHN@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl somefunc(class std::vector<class A,class std::allocator<class A> > &)" (?somefunc@@YAHAEAV?$vector@VA@@V?$allocator@VA@@@std@@@std@@@Z)
```

why it's happening?

Comment: How can the compiler inline a function if it can't see the implementation?

Comment: Are you sure you are linking with `A.o`?

Comment: how you compiling the code?

Comment: @David , yeah, that's right! Thanks. Added definition in .h file, now works.